# Rspec2 Rails 3 Test view without including layout?

Tags: rspec2

I've been trying to test a number of views in my Rails 3 app, but I am getting hung up on the fact that the site's layout calls on AuthLogic's current_user, which I can never seem to set correctly (I've been all over the web looking for that one, but no joy so far).

Then I realized that even when I figure out how to do that right, it's not very DRY to test the current user in *every* view, when it's only called in the layout, so I'm now curious:  Is there a way to test *just* the view (e.g. /app/views/my_model/show.html.erb) without having the layout applied to it?

I realize I'll still need integration tests later, but I wanted to isolate the view specs first if at all possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

RSpec has support to spec the view templates (read more here: https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/docs/view-specs/view-spec).

From my experience these specs **do not render the layout**, can test partials independently and are my preferred way of testing the generated HTML.

PS: you should also install the [webrat](http://rubygems.org/gems/webrat) gem to make your life easier

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'd actually sorted it out a while ago but hadn't updated my post here.  You're right that it doesn't render the layout.  As for the integration testing, I"ve tried both capybara and webrat and wasn't particularly happy with either.